# Trouble between Flash and Generic Handler (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript-3, ashx

im now using FancyUpload (flash upload) to allow user to upload files in a small project.
I use Generic Handler to handler in server when user uploads his file, but i'm getting error: **Can't get session in Generic Handler (.ashx) when using Firefox or Chrome etc except IE**

I read so many solution and finally found out that Flash has some bug that can't send cookie in Firefox or Chrome except IE, so i just want all you guy can help give me a best way to pass this thing

Maybe i can check the session in Flash before it's start to send the file to the server or check session in Generic Handler before save it, just tell me how to do it plzzzz

Thanks in advance and sry 4 my E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to store whatever data you need from the session in the Application with some unique key.  Then pass the unique key to Flash which can pass it back to the server as a url parameter.  Then even though the call isn't part of a session, you can use the url parameter to get to the necessary cached data.

Comment: Thanks for replying, first, i agree with you to store data in Application instead of session, but how can i know when the user is end of session (logout or something...)?

Comment: @Chrno Love, in this case, as soon as the upload is done, you can remove the data from the Application cache.

Comment: Not quite good, is there anyway to get the session object from sessionID? maybe sending the sessionID through the flash to server then decode it is the good idea? what do you think Sam?

Comment: @Chrno Love, It's possible to use cookieless sessions which pass the session id in the url, but I like my way better.  I'm not sure if you can use cookieless sessions for just some calls or if the whole site has to use them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic2

Comment: Can you write me some code how to get session object from sessionID plz?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with SWFUpload. The solution is to pass sessionID to the flash object (and forward it to the upload handler using post or query string). To restore session you can create 'fake' session cookie in Application_BeginRequest event (in global.asax).